# How to avoid getting "float division by zero" error message when using hierarchical clustering in the scipy plugin?

Tags: qgis, clustering, scipy

I am trying to use the hierarchical clustering function in the plugin scipy point clustering in order to group individuals that are close to each into populations.  Here is a screenshot of my selections:

[image: screenshot hierarchical clustering]

But every time I try, I get the following error message in the log:

> Algorithm  Hierarchical Clustering starting... Extracting geometries
>
> from the input layer
>
> float division by zero See log for details

I checked for duplicates in locations (perhaps there was a problem dividing by a zero distance).
I also made sure that the points are not multipart by applying the function : "split multipart features to single part" from digitizing toolbar.

Here is a sample of my shapefile:

```
>   wkt_geom    name    lat long
>   Point (286556 5028628)  2501    5028628 286556
>   Point (286479 5028418)  2502    5028418 286479
>   Point (286507 5028404)  2503    5028404 286507
>   Point (286516 5028412)  2504    5028413 286516
>   Point (286519 5028417)  2505    5028417 286519
>   Point (286517 5028428)  2506    5028428 286517
>   Point (286518 5028433)  2509    5028433 286518
>   Point (286510 5028426)  2510    5028426 286510
>   Point (286512 5028427)  2511    5028427 286512
>   Point (286503 5028423)  2512    5028423 286503
>   Point (286501 5028429)  2513    5028429 286501
>   Point (286495 5028419)  2514    5028419 286495
>   Point (286509 5028397)  2517    5028397 286509
>   Point (286513 5028392)  2518    5028392 286513
```

Comment: try manually installing v0.1 of the plugin from the QGIS Plugins Site (not using the Plugin manager). I remember having similar problems a while back, at least with the k-means algorithm but going back a version worked. Probably best [to log as an issue](https://github.com/SpatialVision/qgis_scipy_clustering/issues)

Comment: It is a bug. With v0.1, there is no problem at all. Download here: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ScipyPointClustering/version/0.1/ and save to Users/yourname/.qgis2/python/plugins (and extract zip file here). It will show up automatically in plugins manager. I hope to get a more satisfactory answer so I will not post as an answer yet.

Comment: Link no longer seems to work.  I ran into same issue.  Adding small offset fixed problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it is a bug with the plugin. Bug has been [reported](https://github.com/SpatialVision/qgis_scipy_clustering/issues/5) but no response yet from developers.

Using v0.1 resolves the issue. Manually install v0.1 of the plugin from the QGIS Plugins Site (not using the Plugin manager). Download here: plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ScipyPointClustering/version/0.1 and save to Users/yourname/.qgis2/python/plugins (and extract zip file here). It will show up automatically in plugins manager.